# Spotfire - Export tables to the Library Server

Tags: export, spotfire

I found a script that export tables to a local folder. My question is: it is possible to export the same tables to the Library Server? If so, which will be the code needed?

Thanks in advance!

Below you can find the script I found online:

```
import System
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from sys import exit
from System.Windows.Forms import FolderBrowserDialog, MessageBox, MessageBoxButtons, DialogResult
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
from System.IO import File, FileStream, FileMode

#This is a list of Data Tables and their Excel file names. You can see each referenced below as d[0] and d[1] respectively.
tableList = [
            ["TestTable1"],
            ["TestTable2"],
            ]

#imports the location of the file so that there is a default place to put the exports.
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentMetadata
dmd = Application.DocumentMetadata #Get MetaData
path = str(dmd.LoadedFromFileName) #Get Path
savePath = '\\'.join(path.split('\\')[0:-1]) + "\\DataExports\\"

dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The files will be save to "+savePath
                +". Do you want to change location?"
                , "Select the save location", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    # GETS THE FILE PATH FROM THE USER THROUGH A FILE DIALOG instead of using the file location
    SaveFile = FolderBrowserDialog()
    SaveFile.ShowDialog()
    savePath = SaveFile.SelectedPath

#message making sure that the user wants to exporthe files.
dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Export Files."
                                +"  Export Files","Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    for d in tableList: #cycles through the table list elements defined above
        writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.StdfDataWriter)
        table =  Document.Data.Tables[d[0]] #d[0] is the Data Table name in the Spotfire project (defined above)
        filtered = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet() #OR pass the filter
        stream = File.OpenWrite(savePath+'\\'+ d[0] +".stdf") #d[1] is the Excel alias name. You could also use d.Name to export with the Data Table name
        names = []
        for col in table.Columns: 
            names.append(col.Name)
        writer.Write(stream, table, filtered, names)
        stream.Close()

#if the user doesn't want to export then he just gets a message
else:
    dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("ok.")
```

Comment: Any particular spot in your library?

Comment: the idea is to do like the following: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/export/details_on_export_data_to_library.htm, but using a python script...

Comment: this script seems to allow you to change the location where you want it saved--why not just point it to your webserver?

Comment: yes, it does. I could save itin the local server you are right, but what I want to do is to save it within Spotfire, more exactly in the Library folter (if that's possible of course).

Comment: While possible it would t be able to be accessed through a browser. What's the end goal?